# Angular Material checkbox behavior

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material, angular-forms

[Here is a link to the fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndoj5y)

My main issue is that the checkbox's [checked] attribute is binded to a value that is never set to true. Now, why does the toggling work? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Please disregard the file naming for the fork. It was a select-value blitz that I forked and added checkbox stuff.

Edit:
Say I set up [(ngModel)] and bind it to termsAndCondition property. 
I add (ngModelChange) event and always set the termsAndCondition property to false. 
Why does the css still change? (the check and uncheck styling)

Comment: It works as a checkbox. All checkboxes <input type="checkbox"> have the same behaviour. But because it's not binded, the value of termsAndConditionsAccepted will not change with just a click, that's where toggleCheck is needed

Comment: Maybe my wording is confusing. I wanted to demonstrate that the checkbox's [checked] property is bound is always set to false (even in the toggleCheck() function). If I change it around and add [(ngModel)] and bind it to termsAndConditions property and on (ngModelChange) event, I always set the termsAndConditions property to false, why would the checkbox still not be responsive to the ngModel and do its own thing?

Comment: I guess, it is just like you said. Even the simplest of checkboxes just do their own checkboxy thing and toggle/untoggle when you click on them, regardless of what model they are bound to. I'll have to find another way to accomplish what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, the checkbox has that behaviour of toggling its state. If you want to make it non responsive, you may want to use [disabled] attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ngModel to bind the checkbox to a variable in your component.

`<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="termsAndConditionsAccepted">`

Comment: You don't *need*. It's not required.

Answer (score 0):

i found the same issue in angular projects regarding using direct variable.

what works for me all the time is to use a function call instead. e.g.

```
<mat-checkbox [checked]="isAccepted()" (click)="toggleCheck()">
  Accept Terms And Conditions
</mat-checkbox>
```

in your ts, declare isAccepted()

```
  isAccepted() {
    return this.termsAndConditionsAccepted;
  }
```

btw, your toggleCheck is incorrect. should be

```
this.termsAndConditionsAccepted = !this.termsAndConditionsAccepted;
```

Comment: Apologies for the confusion in the function name. I didn't want it to be a toggle. I wanted to demonstrate that the property that the [checked] attribute is bound to always set to false, yet the check and uncheck still occurs.

Comment: hmm.. trying to understand your requirement. when the checkbox is rendered the first time, it will be unchecked (getting the value from termsAndConditionsAccepted). when you click on the checkbox, it will toggle the check status. but since u dun have a bound variable, setting the toggleCheck to modify the value will not work. have u looked at @nana answer. maybe this is what u r looking for.

Comment: I have. Actually, I have edited my question and added more stuff on how to reproduce this while using ngModel and ngModelChange.